# What does private static mean in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, design-patterns

What does mean for a class member to be `private static` in c++. And when should I use `private static` variables?

Comment: Do you mean a member that is both `private` and `static`?

Comment: ``private`` refers to access, ``static`` to class storage. They are orthogonal.

Comment: Did you know about this amazing web site called "google.com", which you can use to look up all kinds of information, like the one you're asking?

Comment: private static member can be found as the "_UniqueInstance" member of the singleton pattern ( see head first design pattern, chapter 5 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifier `private` restricts access to class methods and class friends.

The `static` identifier indicates there is only 1 instance of the variable to be shared among all children.

So, `private static` means a data member that has only one instance, regardless of the number of instances, and only class methods and class friends can access it.

Answer (score 2):

> *"What does mean for a class member to be `private static` in c++."*

Supposed you have some declaration like

```
class A {
private:
    static const size_t MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
};
```

it means you have a [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE`, that cannot be accessed by any function, but members of class `A`.

> *"And when should I use `private static` variables?"*

If you don't want them being accessible for clients, but being an implementation dependent detail, that's only accessible for the internal implementation of your class.

Answer (score 0):

you can decompose the attributes:

`private` only the class and friend classes can access the variable

`static` there are just one instance of the variable and is accessible by all the instances of the class